# Problem regarding circle inscribed in rectangle

Tags: geometry, circles, quadrilateral

ABCD is a rectangle and inside it a circle is inscribed touching its larger sides, AD and BC. BD is the rectangle's diagonal which intersects the circle in points E and F, forming the chord EF.

Knowing that BE = 3, EF = 9 and FD = 16, find the side BC. I'm currently trying to solve this by finding the radius, knowing that it's a simple matter of applying the Pythagorean theorem. But I'm struggling in expressing the information I have in an helpful way, maybe expressing the diagonal and circle as functions could help? I've been spending some time on this with no avail.

It would look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: Hello @Blue, I am very sorry! Edited the question :)

Comment: Hint: Let the points of tangency be X (on top) and Y. What can we say about $BX^2 $ by applying similar triangles / power of a point? What can we say about $DY^2$? Hence, what is $BC$ and $CD$?

Comment: So... getting started you could observe that the total diagonal length is 28, and so $F$ is more than halfway from $D$ to $C$, so $F$  is more than half way up and we're crossing the top part of the circle...

Comment: @Blue Great comment! Hope this will be adopted as an Automatic Response to teach others rather the responses and closing good questions.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you for the tip, solved it! I didn't actually know the power of a point theorem but it was easy to prove it as part of the exercise

Comment: I think  RD=16 is wrong. An accurate figure shows that FD=6. So the measure of diagonal  BD=18 and $BC\approx 15.2$

Comment: The problem has a single solution (The figure is accurate! FD =16). The result is not nice but attainable. Still interested in a solution? Find similar triangles in which one of the sides is the radius.

Comment: it seems that the large side is $\sqrt{392-28\sqrt{115}}$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $|AD|=|BC|=a$,
$|AB|=|CD|=b$,
$|BG|=|AH|=u$, $|BE|=p=3$, $|EF|=h=9$, $|FD|=q=16$, $|BD|=d=p+h+q=28$.

By the [power of a point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point)
$B$,

\begin{align} 
u&=\sqrt{p(p+h)}=6
.
\end{align}

By the [power of a point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point)
$D$,

\begin{align} 
a&=u+\sqrt{q(q+h)}=26
,\\
b&=\sqrt{d^2-a^2}=6\sqrt3
.
\end{align}